# How to call Backing Bean method to fetch the request Header value from Incoming request and forward result to a JSF page

Tags: jsf-2, http-headers, authentication

My requirement is " Our users are Authenticated by External System using SSO". 
On successful authentication the external system returns header variables viz. userId,
firstName, lastName etc to our System. 
Currently I am able to retrieve these header variables using
request.getHeader("userId") in my JSP page.

But I am using JSF 2.0 and not able to figure out as to how this can be done in JSF. I saw one example here on Stack overflow ...

```
Map<String, String> requestHeaders = context.getExternalContext().getRequestHeaderMap(); 
String userName = requestHeaders.get(requestHeaderName);
```

but there was no further response as how this will be invoked on the backing bean.

Any pointer or sample code would be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `context` is here just [the current instance](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/context/FacesContext.html#getCurrentInstance%28%29) of the [`FacesContext`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/context/FacesContext.html). This is a request based threadlocal variable which is always available throughout all the JSF code which is controlled by the `FacesServlet`.

```
FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
Map<String, String> requestHeaders = context.getExternalContext().getRequestHeaderMap(); 
String userName = requestHeaders.get(requestHeaderName); 
// ...
```

You can invoke this in for example the bean's constructor, the bean's `@PostConstruct` method, the bean's action(listener) method, etcetera. The right place depends on the moment you want to collect this information and what you want to do with this information.

Comment: Thanks Balus for the response. For example I have a LoginBean.java and i want to invoke this code in the constructor.  But what should my url look like so that the constructor of my LoginBean would be called. lets say my application is deployed as /web on weblogic. So will the url like http://localhost:7001/web/faces/LoginBean will directly invoke the contructor of LoginBean or do I need to do some configuration mapping somewhere in web.xml or faces-config.xml.

Comment: Just the URL of the view you want to see. `login.xhtml` maybe? You just bind the properties and actions of `LoginBean` to components of that view.